# How to get the json return value

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

If I can get the following string

```
([{"data":{"id":"1","user_name":"tutor","book":"123","role":"Tutor"}}]);
```

How can I alert it? `data.user_name` show **undefined**.

```
    $.getJSON('http://mydomain.com/getmyDetail.php?jsoncallback=?', function(data) {   
        alert(data.user_name);    
    });
    }
```

another question, if I would like to put some value to the URL, such as

> http://mydomain.com/getmyDetail.php?username=XXX&role=XXX

, how to put into getJSON function, directly

`$.getJSON('http://mydomain.com/getmyDetail.php?username='+username'+'&role='+role+'&'jsoncallback=?'` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example, `data` is the variable name for the whole response, and you need the `user_name` element inside the `data` element, so you should probably try something like

```
alert(data[0].data.user_name);
```

Comment: thanks it works, and my second question also work after that.

Answer (score 6):

The `[{` means that this is nested in a single element array.  On top of that, the highest level key of the element is `data`.  Use:

```
alert(data[0].data.user_name);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$.getJSON('http://mydomain.com/getmyDetail.php?jsoncallback=?', { username: 'a', role: 'b' }, function(data) {   
    alert(data[0].data.user_name);    
});
```